# rbind RStudio adding third row name to existing matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rbind

After a long time, I decided to come back to coding in R. As of now, I am just going through the tutorials for remembering the things I learned a year ago:D

Everything was fine until I came across with cbind and rbind function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/349RD.png)

Could you please advise me what can be done to set third row name for xxbigger matrix?
I actually want to resolve this in line 23. 
My question for you guys is: How to define thrid row name for xxbigger matrix in one line?

Thank you,

P.S. Don't put sarcastic comments, so I can come back to this website again:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this more simple way

```
xxbigger <- rbind(xxbig, `#3` = c(84, 24, 68))
```

---

Or in the OP's code, change the indexing outside the `row.names`

```
row.names(xxbigger)[3] <- "#3"
```

Comment: wow, I actually found your first solution very useful:)

My mind just blinked when I saw your second solution outside the rownames)